# Как равномерно распределить нагрузку на ядра?

Tags: node.js, cluster

у нас есть несколько ядер на сервере, все они используются для показа баннеров. Я хочу распределить нагрузку на эти ядра равномерно.

## Например мы хотим показать 1000 баннеров и имеем 10 ядер, а значит каждое ядро должно показать 100 баннеров.

! Я пробовал разделить количество необходимо показываемых баннеров на количество активных ядер. Однако столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами:

? Что если мы хотим показать 3 баннера, а свободных ядер у нас 10, значит нужно дать по одному баннеру на 3 ядра, а не по 0.3 баннера на 10 ядер.

? Что если мы хотим показать 4 баннера, а свободных ядер у нас 3,  значит мы должны одному ядру дать два баннера, а остальным по одному.

Что вы мне посоветуете?

Comment: я не знаю как оно на практике, но теоретически, логичнее всего, в цикле, за первую итерацию, отдавать по 1 баннеру на 1 ядро... если баннеры остались запускать вторую итерацию и т.д.

Comment: Я думал про цикл, но представь себе такую штуку - у нас допустим 1 000 000 баннеров, каждый нужно показать 100 000 раз, а нам нужно нагрузку разбрасывать каждые 5 минут. Этот цикл будет выполняться вечно.